# Is it possible to use custom CDI implementation in Weblogic 12.1.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, cdi, omnifaces, weld

I have Java EE application (web and ejb modules in one ear) and OmniFaces and CDI is used in web part. Everithing fine in Weblogic 12.1.2+ versions, but i neet to deploy this app to Weblogic 12.1.1. And there is issue exists with OmniFaces and old CDI implementation in weblogic - https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/46. OmniFaces authors said that ti is CDI bug.

So, is it possibly to take newer CDI implementation version with my application? And if possibly, how?

Comment: There should be Oracle-provided patches for WebLogic 12.1.1. Have you tried contacting Oracle support on this? Needless to say it's strongly recommended to upgrade entire server itself, 12.1.1 has just too many bugs.

Comment: No way. We already have tried to ask customer to update server, and it is impossible in this year.

Comment: Well, that's awkward. As far as we see/know, it's not possible to provide a custom CDI implementation via webapp for WebLogic. The server itself really has to be patched/upgraded in some way.

Comment: What about prefer-application-package settings in weblogic-application.xml or other deployment descriptors? Is it possibly to initialize custom weld through them?